# Does Stack Overflow have SoftWrap-like things as in Android Studio?

Tags: support

I want to know is there any way to make my code or something to look better (just use the space in a good manner that is available), just like the following is getting the whole in one line:

```
 String chart = "<svg width=\"700\" height=\"297\" aria-label=\"A chart.\" style=\"overflow: hidden;\"><defs id=\"defs\"><clipPath id=\"_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0\"><rect x=\"175\" y=\"57\" width=\"350\" height=\"184\"></rect></clipPath><filter id=\"_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1\"><feGaussianBlur in=\"SourceAlpha\" stdDeviation=\"2\"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx=\"1\" dy=\"1\"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type=\"linear\" slope=\"0.1\"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in=\"SourceGraphic\"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter></defs><rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"700\" height=\"297\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#ffffff\"></rect><g><rect x=\"538\" y=\"57\" width=\"149\" height=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill-opacity=\"0\" fill=\"#ffffff\"></rect><g><rect x=\"538\" y=\"57\" width=\"149\" height=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill-opacity=\"0\" fill=\"#ffffff\"></rect><g><text text-anchor=\"start\" x=\"569\" y=\"68.05\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#222222\">Wynik</text></g><rect x=\"538\" y=\"57\" width=\"26\" height=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#3366cc\"></rect></g></g><g><rect x=\"175\" y=\"57\" width=\"350\" height=\"184\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill-opacity=\"0\" fill=\"#ffffff\"></rect><g clip-path=\"url(http://localhost:8080/summary#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0)\"><g><rect x=\"175\" y=\"57\" width=\"1\" height=\"184\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#cccccc\"></rect><rect x=\"262\" y=\"57\" width=\"1\" height=\"184\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#cccccc\"></rect><rect x=\"350\" y=\"57\" width=\"1\" height=\"184\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#cccccc\"></rect><rect x=\"437\" y=\"57\" width=\"1\" height=\"184\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#cccccc\"></rect><rect x=\"524\" y=\"57\" width=\"1\" height=\"184\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#cccccc\"></rect></g><g><rect x=\"176\" y=\"64\" width=\""+  String.valueOf(getGroupAnswer.get(0).getValue() * 5.79) +"\" height=\"23\" stroke=\"#ffa500\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill=\"#ffa500\"></rect><rect x=\"176\" y=\"101\" width=\""+  String.valueOf(getGroupAnswer.get(1).getValue() * 5.79) +"\" height=\"23\" stroke=\"#b87333\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill=\"#b87333\"></rect><rect x=\"176\" y=\"138\" width=\""+  String.valueOf(getGroupAnswer.get(2).getValue() * 5.79) +"\" height=\"22\" stroke=\"#c0c0c0\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill=\"#c0c0c0\"></rect><rect x=\"176\" y=\"174\" width=\""+  String.valueOf(getGroupAnswer.get(3).getValue() * 5.79) +"\" height=\"23\" stroke=\"#ffd700\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill=\"#ffd700\"></rect><rect x=\"176\" y=\"211\" width=\""+  String.valueOf(getGroupAnswer.get(4).getValue() * 5.79) +"\" height=\"23\" stroke=\"#e5e4e2\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill=\"#e5e4e2\"></rect></g><g><rect x=\"175\" y=\"57\" width=\"1\" height=\"184\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#333333\"></rect></g></g><g></g><g><g><text text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"175.5\" y=\"260.05\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#444444\">0</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"262.75\" y=\"260.05\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#444444\">15</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"350\" y=\"260.05\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#444444\">30</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"437.25\" y=\"260.05\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#444444\">45</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"524.5\" y=\"260.05\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#444444\">60</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"end\" x=\"162\" y=\"80.35\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#222222\">TEST4</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"end\" x=\"162\" y=\"116.95\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#222222\">TEST1</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"end\" x=\"162\" y=\"153.55\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#222222\">TEST5</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"end\" x=\"162\" y=\"190.15\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#222222\">TEST3</text></g><g><text text-anchor=\"end\" x=\"162\" y=\"226.75000000000003\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#222222\">TEST2</text></g></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"350\" y=\"284.4562\" font-family=\"Arial\" font-size=\"13\" font-style=\"italic\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#222222\">Wynik całkowity</text><rect x=\"175\" y=\"273.4062\" width=\"350\" height=\"13\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill-opacity=\"0\" fill=\"#ffffff\"></rect></g></g><g></g></svg>";
```

But I want to wrap it to the width perfectly. If the feature is available, please enlighten me.
Is there is things like softwrap feature in Android Studio

Comment: Automatic line-breaks in code are not available. In a lot of cases and languages introducing a line-break breaks the code or introduces other unwanted effects. In your example, a line-break would most probably introduce a syntax error because that's not how multi-line strings work in most languages.

Comment: yeah, line-break will give me a different result. so what should i do.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic line-breaks in code are not available. In a lot of cases and languages introducing a line-break breaks the code or introduces other unwanted effects. In your example, a line-break would most probably introduce a syntax error because that's not how multi-line strings work in most languages.

There is no general rule on how to format such a code sample because it depends on the language used. You could, for example, format your code like this (but it has to be done manually)

```
String chart =
"<svg width=\"700\" height=\"297\" aria-label=\"A chart.\"" +
          "style=\"overflow: hidden;\">" +
    "<defs id=\"defs\">" +
         "<clipPath id=\"_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0\">" +
             "<rect x=\"175\" y=\"57\" width=\"350\" height=\"184\"></rect>" +
     "</clipPath>" +
...
```

If you have such large code samples as shown in your question, then you should also reconsider if it is really necessary to add everything. Keep in mind that you should always create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not available.

Automatically wrapping code would require showing line numbers, to give a visual indication that the code was automatically wrapped. And due to posts being editable, [adding line numbers could cause problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings/77814#77814):

> One very important drawback that hasn't been mentioned is that editing a post would potentially invalidate all the existing answers and comments referring to a specific line number in a previous revision. [...]